How to form a discrete function using table data
I have table with three column given as $a$, $\alpha_\min$ and $\chi^2$ value respectively. Now a need a function such that we define a function $\alpha_\min$[a_ ], which will order the data table that you have defined in ascending order of $\chi^2$ and then extract the alpha_min value corresponding to the minimum $\chi^2$ value in the sorted table. I have tried the Ordering but it dos work. Please let me know if there is some other way to do it.
TableForm[{{0.95, 0.01, 0.9516524102395575`}, {0.9, 0.0838456, 
   0.00017651695169002194`}, {0.85, 0.295003, 
   0.00281306937265338`}, {0.8, 0.437487, 0.22125292245500258`}, {0.7,
    0.701135, 3.467778186791209`}, {0.6, 0.915587, 
   12.713765652663328`}, {0.5, 1.11048, 25.81960204984133`}, {0.4, 
   1.27876, 42.07377320682969`}, {0.3, 1.41499, 
   61.02588755852117`}, {0.2, 1.51511, 82.35647352296047`}, {0.1, 
   1.5763, 105.82242501504311`}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{""}, {"a", 
    "(\[Alpha]\), \(min\)]\)", 
    "(\[Chi]\), \(2\)]\)"}}]


TableForm only formats output, better use list .

Try
t={{0.95, 0.01, 0.9516524102395575`},{0.9, 0.0838456,  0.00017651695169002194`},
  {0.85, 0.295003,  0.00281306937265338`},{0.8, 0.437487, 0.22125292245500258`},
  {0.7, 0.701135, 3.467778186791209`},{0.6, 0.915587,  12.713765652663328`},
  {0.5, 1.11048, 25.81960204984133`},{0.4,  1.27876, 42.07377320682969`},
  {0.3, 1.41499,  61.02588755852117`},{0.2, 1.51511, 82.35647352296047`},
  {0.1,  1.5763, 105.82242501504311`}};
First[SortBy[t,Last]][[3]]

which returns
0.000176517

Just be careful that you don't use
t=TableForm[{{0.95, 0.01, 0.9516524102395575`},{0.9, 0.0838456,  0.00017651695169002194`},...

because TableForm produces something nice to look at, but usually cannot be used for further calculations.

Another method Last[First[MinimalBy[t,Last]]]

how can i make it a function of "a" so the when i put value of "a" it will give me value of "\alpha_min"

Try using my t=... above followed by fun[a_]:=(Select[t,#[[1]]==a&])[[1,2]];fun[0.4] and it returns 1.27876 etc. Test that carefully and see if it always works for you. There are other ways this can be done. Is there some function you would like to use to select an item from a list?

Here is a version using Ordering :
t={{0.95, 0.01, 0.9516524102395575`},{0.9, 0.0838456,  0.00017651695169002194`},
  {0.85, 0.295003,  0.00281306937265338`},{0.8, 0.437487, 0.22125292245500258`},
  {0.7, 0.701135, 3.467778186791209`},{0.6, 0.915587,  12.713765652663328`},
  {0.5, 1.11048, 25.81960204984133`},{0.4,  1.27876, 42.07377320682969`},
  {0.3, 1.41499,  61.02588755852117`},{0.2, 1.51511, 82.35647352296047`},
  {0.1,  1.5763, 105.82242501504311`}};

index=Ordering[t[[All,3]]];(*{2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}*)
t[[First[index]]]  (*{0.9, 0.0838456, 0.000176517}*)
t[[First[index]]][[3]]  (* 0.000176517  *)


how can i make it a function of "a" so the when i put value of "a" it will give me value of "\alpha_min"

For this i want to define a function alpha_min [a_ ], which will order the data table that you have defined in ascending order of chi^2 and then extract the alpha_min value corresponding to the minimum chi^2 value in the sorted table.

@Amnish Try fun[tt_]:= Module[{index=Ordering[tt[[All,3]]]},tt[[First[index]]][[3]]  ]
